# Bind DataGrid to List<T>, but only show selection of T's properties

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid

So, there's a custom class, `Material`:

```
class Material
{
    public string Qty { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
    public string PONumber { get; set; }
    public string RigName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string ShipTo { get; set; }
    public string ShipVia { get; set; }

    public Material()
    {
        Qty = "5";
        Description = "This is a test";
        Supplier = "Wal-Mart";
        PONumber = "23423";
        RigName = "Test Rig";
        ProjectName = "Test Project";
        ShipTo = "Kevin";
        ShipVia = "Danny";
    }
}
```

I have a `list` of `Material`:

```
var myList = new List<Material>
                 {
                     new Material()
                 };
```

And it's set as the item source for my `DataGrid`:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = myList;
```

Now, in the XAML, if I set the `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`, it creates the headers for `dataGrid1` based upon the properties of `Material`. However, I only want 4 columns, `Qty`, `Description`, `Supplier`, and `PONumber`. So, I wrote the following:

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          Name="dataGrid1">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty"
                                            Binding="{Binding XPath=@Qty}" />

                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description"
                                            Binding="{Binding XPath=@Description}" />

                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Supplier"
                                            Binding="{Binding XPath=@Supplier}" />

                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="PO#"
                                            Binding="{Binding XPath=@PONumber}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

My problem is that now, `dataGrid1` is empty. I have the feeling I'm missing something completely silly, and I'm hoping a fresh pair of eyes can help me spot this.

So, my question is, am I going about this the wrong way? Is there a way to bind the `List<Material>` to `dataGrid1` and only show the columns that I want?

The websites I based my attempts on are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtextcolumn.aspx) and [here](http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bindings are wrong: you should use `Path` instead of `XPath`. The `XPath` property is only used when binding to an XML data source.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty" Binding="{Binding Path=Qty}" />
```

Note that you can omit the `"Path="` part for brevity:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty" Binding="{Binding Qty}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [`XPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath.aspx), try [`Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) and give exact proprty name without $.

`XPath` is used for xml based data source. For objects, `Path` property binding is used.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be tring to `Bind` to an `XPath` which is used for direct `Xml` bindings, You only need to use `Path` or just declare the property.

Example:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Qty" Binding="{Binding Qty}" />
```